# Error running apt-get install on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, apt

When I run `apt-get install mysql-server` I get the following error:

> Failed to fetch
>   http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-dfsg-5.1/mysql-server_5.1.41-3ubuntu12.6_all.deb
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.177 80] E: Unable to fetch some
>   archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

This is a rather old server, so I'm thinking maybe something is out of date?  However, I have no idea how to fix it.  I'd appreciate any help I could get!

Comment: Have you tried running `apt-get update` as the helpful error message suggested?

Comment: @Ladadadada - Thanks!  That fixed it.  Feel free to submit an answer and I'll accept it.  I probably should have tried that first, but I got it stuck in my head that the repositories were no longer at that address and an update wouldn't work any better..

Comment: It's literally spelled out in the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried running `apt-get update` as the helpful error message suggested?

Comment: +1 for reading the error message